# Shibboleth login

Tags: angular, adfs, shibboleth

I have an application created in Angular in which I have to implement authentication via shibboleth and adfs, that is, once I go to the /login path I will be directed to the adfs page where it will be possible to enter the username and password. Once inserted and logged in I assume that I will be directed to the path of my /home application, at this point I would like to understand how I can get the logged in user data directly from Angular (I have no backend services or anything else) Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called SAML2.0 SP (Service Provider).

Unfortunately, you will need a backend to handle the SAML auth flow.

The best (fastest) approach would be to use a no-backend tech (the services that create a backend for you) like Firebase, Supabase, etc., Or use any identity management service that does the SAML for you.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42652073/exchange-metadata-from-shibboleth-sp-and-idp/42664518#42664518) are some examples of how to connect with Shibboleth SP and idP.