# What will be the Entity ID for my 1 IIS server hosting 2 websites?

Tags: php, iis, server, shibboleth, siteminder

I have 1 IIS server hosting multiple websites.
It uses Siteminder agent as an authentication tool.
I am currently migrating Siteminder to shibboleth.

My website's paths are like:

https://www.hostname.corp/website1

https://www.hostname.corp/website2

https://www.hostname.corp/website3

Hostname is same for all websites, just the directories are different.

In the Shibboleth configuration file (shibboleth2.xml), in  tag I have to mention the entityID.

So what should I mention in the EntityID field? Will it be the same, i.e

**https://www.hostname.corp/shibboleth**

or

Will it be different for all websites, i.e

**https://www.hostname.corp/Website1/shibboleth**  and so on.

I am performing this migration for the first time.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494941/what-entityid-to-choose-to-configure-service-provider-sp-in-shibboleth

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What entityId to choose to configure Service Provider (SP) in shibboleth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494941/what-entityid-to-choose-to-configure-service-provider-sp-in-shibboleth)